# How to search XML Tags based on a ID using XPathDocument?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpathdocument

Below mentioned is a part of my XML:

```
<ParentNode>
    <NewCommentID>UniqueID02</NewCommentID>
    <Comment>
        <CommentId>UniqueID01</CommentId> 
        <CommentDesc>Some comments</CommentDesc> 
        <CommentTypeCd>Code1</CommentTypeCd> 
        <CreatedDt>2013-11-29</CreatedDt> 
        <CreatedByUserId>user01</CreatedByUserId> 
        <GivenName>Mitchell</GivenName> 
        <Surname>Johnson</Surname> 
    </Comment>
    <Comment>
        <CommentId>UniqueID02</CommentId> 
        <CommentDesc>Some Comments....</CommentDesc> 
        <CommentTypeCd>Code2</CommentTypeCd> 
        <CreatedDt>2013-11-29</CreatedDt> 
        <CreatedByUserId>user02</CreatedByUserId> 
        <GivenName>Mike</GivenName> 
        <Surname>Jobs</Surname> 
    </Comment>
</ParentNode>
```

I want to get the details of all the nodes under Comment section, but the which section to select will be decided by Node (NewCommentID).
In the above example as the value in 'NewCommentID = UniqueID02', I want to fetch all the tags and their values under Comment section where the CommentID = UniqueID02 using XPathDocument.

Can someone guide how to achieve the same using VB.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
Dim xpathDoc As New XPathDocument("Path_to_xml_file.xml")
Dim navigator As XPathNavigator

navigator = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator()
Dim result = navigator.Select("//Comment[./CommentId=../NewCommentID]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked..
however, I would like to ask one more question that.. what if I don't have NewCommentID tag in the XML and have that value in some other variable apart from XML, will it be possible to achieve the above scenario?

Comment: simply replace `../NewCommentID` in the XPath with your variable value no? If that is not what you meant, consider to post new question, elaborate more on that new problem. Ideally, there should be *one specific question in one post* (for many reasons, f.e to make it more manageable, so future visitor doesn't get confused trying to figure out what kind of problem being solved here).